# Como trazer para a aplicação um array que está num arquivo separado?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um arquivo JS (dados.js) que contem um array com as informações abaixo:

```js
 module.exports = [
        {
          "photo": "https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/e6c4b347-49c7-4840-8c00-df36a2a273da.jpg?aki_policy=x_large",
          "property_type": "Apartamento",
          "name": "Apartment in Son Parc, wonderful views",
          "price": 433
        },
        {
          "photo": "https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/4a5326cb-95e4-4220-a4d8-c91f50cf784c.jpg?aki_policy=xx_large",
          "property_type": "Apartamento",
          "name": "APARTAMENTO IDEAL PAREJAS EN SON PARC",
          "price": 368
        },
      ]
```

e preciso utilizar essas informações no HTML. Como faço pro JavaScript reconhecer esse arquivo? Eu estou tentando esse comando, mas dá erro.

```js
const dados = require('./dados.js');
console.log(dados);
```

Tô fazendo o console.log pra testar se trouxe as informações, depois eu continuo o trabalho.

Comment: Mas está a tentar importar esses dados num outro ficheiro javascript ou no html?

Comment: Estou colocando a importação no javaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Editando a resposta conforme comentário abaixo:

```html
<html>
  <head>    
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import dados from '/dados.js';

console.log(dados);
```

dados.js

```js
export default [
  {
    "photo": "https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/e6c4b347-49c7-4840-8c00-df36a2a273da.jpg?aki_policy=x_large",
    "property_type": "Apartamento",
    "name": "Apartment in Son Parc, wonderful views",
    "price": 433
  },
  {
    "photo": "https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/4a5326cb-95e4-4220-a4d8-c91f50cf784c.jpg?aki_policy=xx_large",
    "property_type": "Apartamento",
    "name": "APARTAMENTO IDEAL PAREJAS EN SON PARC",
    "price": 368
  },
]
```

Comment: Se o browser não tiver suporte a Ecmascript6 pode-se fazer os imports com o module.exports normalmente!

Comment: Alterei o script para:
```js
import dados from '/dados.js';

console.log(dados);
```
e apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

import dados from '/dados.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)

Comment: Por favor, especifique qual servidor, framework que você está usando.

Comment: eu estou fazendo uma atividade que sugeriu usar JavaScript puro. não sei se não entendi direito, mas eu estava achando que dava pra fazer sem instalar nada, apenas configurando direto no arquivo de scrips... mas se não tiver jeito eu conheço um pouco do express

Comment: Você está incluindo o script via html como eu coloquei na resposta?